# Any_Match or Contains with Multiple Parameters

Tags: sql, presto, trino

I have a sample table

| id | region |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | LAX |
| 1 | LAS |

I then grab all the regions associated to that ID with the following:

`ARRAY_SORT(ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_AGG(region)))` as all_regions

, `any_match(all_regions, s -> s like '%LAS%')` as any_match

, `contains(all_regions, 'LAX')` as contains

Result:

| id | all_regions | any_match | contains |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [LAS, LAX] | true | true |

***Desired Result:***

I want to find all the id's associated with these two regions, if they have any of these 2 regions in their array, I want it to evaluate to TRUE.

I know how to use the functions, but I'm not sure how to add multiple parameters.

**My attempts:**

any_match(all_regions, s -> s like '%LAS%',e -> e like  '%RNO%'),

any_match(all_regions, s -> s like '%LAS%' or '%RNO%'),

contains(all_regions, 'LAX' or 'RNO')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the description [`arrays_overlap`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#arrays_overlap) should do the trick:

> tests if arrays `x` and `y` have any non-null elements in common. Returns null if there are no non-null elements in common but either array contains null.

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(id, all_regions) AS (
   VALUES (1, array['LAX']),
        (2, array['LAS']),
        (3, array['42'])
)

-- query
SELECT *, 
   arrays_overlap(all_regions, array['LAX', 'LAS'])
FROM dataset;
```

Or you can use `IN` in `any_match`:

```sql
-- query
SELECT *, 
       any_match(all_regions, r -> r in ('LAX', 'LAS'))
FROM dataset;
```

Output:

| id | all_regions | _col2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [LAX] | true |
| 2 | [LAS] | true |
| 3 | [42] | false |